# Mysql Query for inserting from one table to another on Multiple conditions and columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, case

I have a table named as test table in which I have total of 8 columns as such (`Roll_no`, `Student_name`, `Company1`, `Pass_fail1`, `Company2`, `Pass_fail2`, `Company3`, `Pass_fail3`).
I have to insert the data from test table to another table (say Interview table).
Columns of Interview table are (`Roll_no`, `Student_name`, `Company1`, `Company2`, `Company3`);

The condition for insertion is:
If a student has passed the test of Company1 (i.e `pass_fail1=1`) then he is eligible for interview of Company1,and same conditions for remaining two companies.
So, Company1 will be inserted in interview table only if `pass_fail1=1.`

if `pass_fail=0` then do not enter the name of the company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO interviews (Rollno,Student_name,Company1,Company2,Company3)
SELECT Rollno, Student_name, 
      (CASE WHEN Pass_fail1 = 1 THEN Company1 ELSE '' END) Company1, 
      (CASE WHEN Pass_fail2 = 1 THEN Company2 ELSE '' END) Company2, 
      (CASE WHEN Pass_fail3 = 1 THEN Company3 ELSE '' END) Company3 
FROM test
```